# Create layered PSD from PNG sequence with Imagemagick from batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, imagemagick, psd

I am using an animation software that outputs the animation as PNG sequences labeled filename-001.png, filename-002.png etc. I'd like to use imagemagick's *convert* to compile a PSD so I can edit it fast in Photoshop.

I need the Windows batch file to **get all the png files from the folder the batch file resides in** (or alternatively **drag and drop the first image** in the sequence or drag and drop the folder) and **convert them in a layered PSD file**.

The label ideally should be the filename part (e.g. for layer 2 = "filename-002")

Currently my batch is as follows:

```
convert
( -page +0+0 -label "label1" "filename-001.png"[0] -background none -mosaic -set colorspace RGB )
( -page +0+0 -label "label2" "filename-002.png"[0] -background none -mosaic -set colorspace RGB )
( -page +0+0 -label "label3" "filename-003.png"[0] -background none -mosaic -set colorspace RGB )
( -page +0+0 -label "label4" "filename-004.png"[0] -background none -mosaic -set colorspace RGB )
( -clone 0--1 -background none -mosaic ) -reverse "out.psd"
```

This of course converts the png images that I input manually, I need to make this more automatic.

Also finally, **the resulting PSD has its layers opacity-locked**, I'd like them not to be locked so I can edit the PSD faster in Photoshop.

Comment: Which specific aspect of that is troubling you?

Comment: do you know about `%1%` in .bat scripting? Otherwise it looks like you're good to make your animation. Good luck.

Comment: So that is your batch-file?  I have never seen bat code that looks like that.

Comment: The code you posted is not a Windows [tag:batch-file] (with an extension `.bat` or `.cmd`), is it?

Comment: I think this is 1 command broken into multiple lines, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I am aware about %1, just not really sure how to loop through each file and add each file as layer using that. And yeah it is actually a batch (.bat) file that I am currently using but manually adding the image frames (within the brackets). I did break up the code into separate lines for better visibility on this site.

Comment: Is this 1 or multiple lines in the batch-file?

Comment: Yes, it is separate lines which I broke up so it shows up better on stackoverflow, if you remove the linebreaks it will work fine.

Comment: A couple of notes... you can set `-background none` immediately after `convert` and the setting will persist through all layers without restating it every time. Also, you need `-reverse` after the final `-clone 0--1` otherwise your preview will be stacked in the reverse order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this, although I can't test it because I don't have imagemagic myself:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set number=1
set "command=convert"
for %%f in (*.png) do (
  set "command=!command! ^( -page +0+0 -label ^"label!number!^" ^"%%~nxf^"[0] -background none -mosaic -set colorspace RGB ^)"
  set /a number=!number!+1
)
set "command=%command% ^( -clone 0--1 -background none -mosaic ^) -reverse ^"out.psd^""
%command%
pause
```

I think the opacity problem can be found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19259)

Comment: This worked fine thanks, though the layers do not get the filename part but I am certain I can get that with %~nxf or something. Also the layers are still opacity-locked but after some searching, I think this could be a bug/feature(?) of imagemagick.

Comment: What do you mean the layers do not get the filename part? Do you mean the label name? Seeing as you called your labels label1..label4 I though you numerically wanted to name them.

Comment: are the numbers always the last 3 characters of the filename? then you can use %%~nf and substring.

Comment: By the way, if my question solved your problem you should click the check to the left of it to mark it as correct. If it didn't feel free to leave a comment saying what's going wrong and I'll try to help.

Comment: @user780756, when you provide obfuscated examples, you get obfuscated code.

Comment: @Squashman, the above code is not obfuscated, it's regular commandline variables

Comment: I think @Squashman means that the fact the labels are called label1 etc doesn't show that you want to call the labels like the images